# using sed i need to replace value

Tags: shell, sed, jq

```
{
    "test.yaml": "# Copyright (c) 2019-2020 .\n# All Rights Reserved.\n#\n#\n\trace1:\n  - trace-id:\n      - \"immm-0555555555\"\n      - \"mncid-6666666666\"\n    test-service:\n      - \"test-data\"\n    proposed-date: 2019-06-26T16:32:52\n    start-date: 2019-06-27T10:00:00\n    end-date: 2050-06-27T10:30:00\n    test-type: \"HIGH\""
}
```

above is the json content basically i need to update startdate enddate proposeddate i have used sed command to update

```
sed -i -e 's/start-date: .*\\n/start-date: 2013-06-27T10:00:00\\n/' /dummyfile.json
```

after this command execution

```
{
    "test.yaml": "# Copyright (c) 2019-2020 .\n# All Rights Reserved.\n#\n#\n\trace1:\n  - trace-id:\n      - \"immm-0555555555\"\n      - \"mncid-6666666666\"\n    test-service:\n      - \"test-data\"\n    proposed-date: 2019-06-26T16:32:52\n    start-date: 2013-06-27T10:00:00\n       test-type: \"HIGH\""
}
```

but this updating like this end-date is also deleted

Comment: ravinder can i know where i am doing wrong

Comment: The wildcard `.*` means "all the text from here onwards". You should not use regex to parse JSON anyway.

Comment: It looks like the value of the "test.yaml" key is supposed to be YAML, but the string is invalid as YAML because of the tab ("\t"). If the value was valid YAML, then you could use a YAML tool in conjunction with jq to make the changes you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON doesn't look 100% valid but with valid JSON, use jq e.g.:

```
jq '.start-date="2013-06-27T10:00:00" | .end-date="2013-06-27T10:00:00" | .proposed-date="2013-06-27T10:00:00"' dummy-file.json
```

Comment: json is proper only i verified in jsonlint and i tried using jq due to special character i am not able to parse properly thanks in advance Raman Sailopal

Answer (score 0):

tripleee told why your command behaved as you observed. Now to rectify it, you have to change the *greedy* `.*` to some expression which doesn't match more than wanted; this can be an expression of fixed length as `....-..-..T..:..:..` or an expression of variable length which doesn't extend to unwanted characters as `[^\]*` (the `[` `]` denote a [Bracket Expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) *that shall match a specific set of single characters*, the `^` at the start denotes a *non-matching list*, and the *list* consists of only the char `\`, i. e. the `[^\]*` matches any number (`*`) of characters which are not `\`, so the match only reaches till the end of the start timestamp and stops at the following `\`).

Comment: this worked for me [^\]* but i need to know what it does i a m new to sed can u plz explain

Comment: I added explanation and documentation link.

Comment: it was very helpfull doc thanks for sharing " An ordinary character in the list should only match that character, but may match any single character that collates equally with that character; for example, "[abc]" is an RE that should only match one of the characters 'a', 'b', or 'c'."

Comment: my question is [^ " }]* is there any way that bracket expression accepts and only look for both "} and then do changes

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. It would help if you gave an example text fragment where you want to match something.

Answer (score 0):

A jq-only solution can easily be built-up using `sub` beginning like so:

```
."test.yaml" |= sub("(?<key>start-date: )(?<date>[-0-9:T]+)"; "\(.key)2013-06-27T10:00:00")
```

You would add additional `sub` filters (like the one shown) to the RHS for each key of interest, using the pattern:

```
."test-yaml" |= (sub(...) | sub(...) ...)
```

This approach would be particularly advantageous if the replacement string must be computed based on the string being replaced.